# Error installing feeder/feedr library in python

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pytorch

I am trying to run a code which uses feeder (feedr on git repository) library. I am getting error while installing it. I have tried pip, cloning git, and previous versions but still getting same error on all PC. Please tell how to solve it or any alternative for feeder. Original code link is https://github.com/nashory/DeLF-pytorch/tree/master/notebook [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR8bO.png)

Comment: The error message is:

AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-svrfabbc/distribute/

Answer (score 0):

`feedr` [uses](https://github.com/nir0s/feedr/blob/de47d432f45c6b752ecf36140606f33de4dabf75/setup.py#L60) `infi.docopt_completion==0.2.1` which in turn [uses](https://github.com/Infinidat/infi.docopt_completion/blob/98064557513d81ba5650451b0ff21d55d1c24c16/buildout.cfg#L11) `distribute` which [is so old](https://pypi.org/project/distribute/#history) (last release in 2013) that it could hardly be installed in modern Python. I failed to install it in Python 2.7.

In short: the project `feedr` is old, outdated and abandoned. Forget about it. Or try to update in manually to use newer versions of dependencies. You can send pull request(s) to the author.